# How to correctly change core code in Woocommerce? (Remove error validation on Price fields)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

we are setting up a website with wordpress and woocommerce. Woocommerce is just a product catalogue, as the website does not act as a shop.

The customer operates with two kinds of prices, one for private consumers & one for businesses. Some products are less expensive for private consumers, and some are less expensive for businesses. For this we have decided to use the two native price fields in WooCommerce (Sales price and Regular price). The problem however, is that in the woocommerce_admin.js file there exists some code that throws an error (and clears the input) whenever the price entered in Sales price is higher than regular price.

This makes total sense, and its a great function for normal usage. But in our strange case, this does not work. We need to remove the following code from the file:

```
if ( sale_price >= regular_price ) {
       $( this ).val( '' );
}
```

and

```
if ( sale_price >= regular_price ) {
         $( document.body ).triggerHandler( 'wc_add_error_tip', [ $(this), 'i18_sale_less_than_regular_error' ] );
} else {
         $( document.body ).triggerHandler( 'wc_remove_error_tip', [ $(this), 'i18_sale_less_than_regular_error' ] );
}
```

However, altering core files in Wordpress/Woocommerce is not advised. Because the second we update either wordpress or woocommerce, our changes will get overwritten.

In themes however, you are able to create child-themes to avoid this.

**My question: Is there any way of changing/removing core code, without it being replaced in future updates?**

Comment: If the JS that is giving you troube is in its own file, you could deregister it. Or you could add your own JS that removes that trigger. But in general, I wouldn't use the Sale price, just use a plugin that adds role/group based prices.

Comment: @janh Those lines are in the middle of a lot of other functionality. So deregistering is not an option unfortunately. And as you can see from the code, they are not a part of any functions - so not sure how i can remove the triggers? Any tips? In terms of not using sales price, I`m afraid thats not an option right now (too many other things are connected to these fields atm)

Comment: If the validation only runs in JS and not serverside, you could maybe transmit the data with another field name and add a hook that will then update the product when it's saved and set the sale price accordingly.